# Spawning a new thread/process within TWebModule Handler

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I have a Delphi **TWebModule** ISAPI based project running on Apache.  One of my event handlers contains logic that can take minutes to process.  I would like to spawn a separate process/thread to perform the logic and return html immediately back to the browser.  The html would have AJAX client side calls to get periodic updates of the process progress.

I have tried using **TThread**, but find it waits for the **Execute** code to end before returning.

Example:

```
  procedure Tmainweb.DoLongProcess(Sender: TObject; Request: TWebRequest;
    Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
  var
    ProcessThread: TProcessThread;
  begin
    ProcessThread := TProcessThread.Create(True);
    ProcessThread.Execute;
    Handled := True;
    Response.Content := '<html><body>Processing - would also include ajax stuff to get periodic updates</body></html>
  end;
```

**TProcessThread** is my processing thread which may take minutes to complete.  When I run this application I thought control would continue immeidately after **ProcessThread.Execute**.  But it does not.  Instead it waits for the code in the **Execute** procedure to complete.

How can I accomplish this?  How to I spawn a asynchronous process so that the browser is not in a wait state?

Comment: Can't you just serve the page and let the javascript/ajax client initiate the long process instead?

Comment: Guess I could try that.  AJAX is a bit new to me.  And ideally I would not want the clientside to initiate this process.  Would rather rely on the server side to.

Comment: Before answering, it's important to ask some questions: 1.  Is my assumption that this is a web application served up by a web server?  2.  ISAPI or CGI?

Comment: Well, in the end it is still the client (browser) who initiates the process (by visiting the URL).

Comment: @NickHodges: ISAPI on Apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just spinning on Darian's answer. 
Here's an example which answers your question :

```
type
  TProcessThread = class(TThread)
  protected 
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;

constructor TProcessThread.Create;
begin
 inherited Create( false);
 Self.FreeOnTerminate := true;
end;

procedure TProcessThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Self.Terminated do begin
    {- Do some heavy work }
  end;
  {- free by myself at last ! }
end;
```

-

```
// In your TmainWeb.DoLongProcess
ProcessThread := TProcessThread.Create; // Thread will free itself when ready.
Handled := True;
```

Comment: Ok - getting somewhere here.  I modified my descendant class to include "FreeOnTerminiate = True" and when I create it changed the CreateSuspended from True to False.  Before I was calling the constructor with CreateSuspended = True and then calling Execute.

Comment: Good, just do not explicitly call `Execute` since this is done by the thread class itself.

Answer (score 2):

There's not quite enough info to give a correct answer, but I am assuming TProcessThread inherits from TThread somehow.  If so, then you create the thread and then Start it.  The execute method will be called within the child thread and is not to be called directly.

```
ProcessThread.FreeOnTerminate := True
ProcessThread.Start() // Later versions of Delphi
//or  ProcessThread.Resume;  in earlier versions of Delphi to start a suspended thread
```

Comment: I could not find TProcessThread class.  Searched all of the CodeGear Delphi 2007 code.

Comment: @Darian, there's no [`TThread.Start`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TThread.Start) in Delphi 2007 yet (I know Delphi version is missing in this question). Fixed :)

Comment: There is no need to create the thread suspended. Just set `FreeOnTerminate := True;` within the thread create method.

Comment: @MSchenkel, the TProcessThread class is something you would define in your code, a class derived from `TThread`. Otherwise your question is unclear.

Comment: If .Start() is not available, use .Resume()